# how to automatic plot targets on tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying automatic plot targets on tradingview, like this image

[image],

but I failed, the TP will Recurrence several times.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

```
plotshape(  (close>TP1_value)  , title="TP1_Reached", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, color=green, transp=0, text="TP1_Reached", textcolor=green, size=size.large)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, `close>TP1_value` is true for multiple bars. If you want to plot only once, you can use a variable.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

TP1_value = input(title="Take Profit Price", defval=10000)

var isTP1reached = false  // Use this variable to see if TP1 hass already been reached

takeProfit1 = not isTP1reached and (close > TP1_value)  // If not already reached TP1 and TP condition is true

if (takeProfit1)
    isTP1reached := true

plotshape(series=takeProfit1, title="Take Profit 1", text="Take Profit 1", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
```

[image]

As you can see from the image above, it only plots once. Of course you need to reset the variable according to your needs in order to use it again.